# Grains repetead code for actions in controllers

Tags: grails, filter, controller, action

I have already posted this question, but i realised the aswer was not what i was looking for. Imagine this controller:

```
    class exampleController{

    def action1 = {
           ...

[lala: lala, lele: lele]}

           ...
    }
    def action15 = {
           ...

[lala: lala, lele: lele]
```

}

I want to be able to return in all the action in this controller the same params. Imagining this:

```
def book = Book.findAllByIsbn(Isbn.get(1))  
[book: book]
```

Is there any way of doing this, besides writing all the same code on all the actions? I have tried this method and it isnt working:

```
def action5 = {getModel()}

  private getModel() {
    def book = Book.findAllByIsbn(Isbn.get(1))  
[book: book]  
  }
}
```

It is not working because, and my thought is, he doest accept multiple [return1: aaa, return2: bbb]. Any suggestion please ? I have also tried filters like in here: [Grails controllers repeated code for all actions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6268915/grails-controllers-repeated-code-for-all-actions)
but i couldnt managed to make it work. I would apreciated a detailed explanaintion about any of the solutions if possible:p Thanks in advanced,
VA

Comment: Is your question how you can reuse one method or closure for different controller actions?

Comment: Once again, who 'he' doesn't accept multiple what? The `getModel()` function actually can `return` a Map with multiple values, and that looks exactly like what you need.

Comment: @Ruben basically, i want to be able to use repeat that code in all the actions of that controller. Call it what you want

Comment: imagining my action already have something like this [fav: fav, par: par]. And then i call getModel(). For some reason, and i dont know why, it isnt working, but if i copy the code manually and join the both [..] [..] returns it does work, i want to figure that out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it's not the same model, but a model with a repeated part.

You should know that the return value is an ordinary `Map`.

So, return value can be constructed like `return getCommonModel() + [book: currentBook]` where `getCommonModel()` returns another Map.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return the same model from all your actions, this approach should work:

```
class ExampleController {

  def action5 = {getModel()}
  def action1 = {getModel()}
  //etc.

  private getModel() {
    def book = Book.findAllByIsbn(Isbn.get(1))  
    [book: book]  
  }
}
```

If you want to return the same model **and** render the same view from all your actions, you could return the same `ModelAndView` from each action, but then I would ask why do you need separate actions if they're all doing exactly the same thing?

I don't really understand your hypothesis

> It is not working because, and my thought is, he doest accept multiple `[return1: aaa, return2: bbb]`

If your suggesting that `getModel()` can only return a model with a single entry, I find that very hard to believe. Can you elaborate a bit on this, or post some more information (e.g. stacktrace, unit test) that shows how/why it's not working?

### Update

After reading your comments below I think I finally understand what you want to achieve, which is to append the model returned by `getModel()` (above) to the model returned by various other actions. Does this work:

```
class ExampleController {

  def action5 = {
    def action5Model = [foo: 'bar']
    return addBookModel(action5Model)
  }

  def action1 = {
    def action1Model = [foo2: 'bar2']
    return addBookModel(action1Model)
  }
  //etc.

  private Map addBookModel(Map model) {
    def book = Book.findAllByIsbn(Isbn.get(1))  
    model.book = book
    return model
  }
}
```

This approach will only work when you want to add the book model within a single controller. If you want to add the book model in several controllers you can do this by:

- putting `addBookModel` in an abstract class that the controllers extend
- putting `addBookModel` in a class that is mixed-in with the controllers (using `@Mixin`)
- putting `addBookModel` in a filter that is executed after the controller actions

Comment: sure, i'll try to explain better. I have severel pages in my website, and in both pages i need to have acess to the ${book} param. So, basically and to do it in the hard way, i would copy all this code: def book = Book.findAllByIsbn(Isbn.get(1)) to all the controllers, and then mix this: [book: book] with the other params returned in each individual action. The problem is, that's not an easy thing to do, because my action are much more complex than this, and i'll be lost in all that repeated code. I have tried your iniccial aproach (the getModel()) thing, and for some reason it isnt work

Comment: I tried something like this in my action1: def author = Author.get(1) getModel() [author: author]. Altought i can have acess to "author" in my gsp page, i dont have acess to book and that is my main problem. If i manually copy the code and mix the params, it works

Comment: found the answer. Instead of getModel() which wont return me the value i wanted, i did this: [ret: ret, ret2: getModel().book] and know it is working. Thank you anyway for the answer and the time spent with me.

Comment: yes it works, thank you very much:p altought in my case i find @victor's answer easier. thanks

Comment: actually, my answer is pretty much identical to his :)

Answer (score -1):

If you are using exact same model in multiple pages. I would recommend you use a taglib for it.